# How to read only the number from json file with python - discord.py?

Tags: python, discord.py

I have a file with the following content:

```
{
    "Youtube tutorial bot test": {
        "ivan4o assistant": 0,
        "kurwa qvor": 1
    }
}
```

And I want it to read only the number.

I've tried with this code:

```
def warns_check(member: discord.Member):
    with open('warns.json', 'r') as f:
        warns = json.load(f)
        warns[str(member.name)]
    return warns

@client.command()
async def checkwarns(ctx, member: discord.Member):
    warns = warns_check(member)
    await ctx.send(f"{member.name} has {warns} warnings")
```

And it reads the whole file.
How to fix this?

Comment: I'm not sure I'm following...you want to read the number (i.e `values`) from a JSON file in python? Parse them. Your line: `warns = json.load(f)` reads the content of the file, parse it to get the data/values (as they are the only numbers you show) to get what you want. `.items()` or `.values()` on your `dict` will allow you to access the items you want

Answer (score 1):

> I want it to read only the number.

In order to fetch the number you would need to access it using

```
warns["Youtube tutorial bot test"][member.name]
```

> And it reads the whole file. How to fix this?

You are reading essentially a text file so you always need to load the whole file. I would suggest using a database (sqlite or Mongo are good options). Using a json file will also present issues with concurrency.

Furthermore...

I would suggest using `member.id` which is a unique ulong (int in Python) unlike the name which users can change

Answer (score 1):

With "it reads the whole file" I assume you mean it *returns* all the contents?

It returns the whole file because you're returning the whole file. The second line takes a specific value out, but you don't assign it to anything, so the line doesn't do anything.

```py
warns = json.load(f)  # <- Read whole file & assign to "warns"
warns[str(member.name)]  # <- Does nothing
return warns  # <- "warns" still contains the whole file
```

You'll want to return that specific portion instead of the whole file.

```py
return warns[str(member.name)]
```

Also - that JSON fragment has 2 levels before it gets to a number, so there's a key access missing.

Answer (score 1):

Also you should use the users id rather of their name, as they can change their name. And I suggest using a database like SQLite in your case for it as just a single error while saving the file can either break your data or your whole file will be empty.
Check the [Python SQLite module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html) for this.